# recursive program to get children of nodes

Tags: c#

I have the following table as example

```
PNLId   PNLCode PNLParentId Operator    Sign
0      
49  C   51  +   NULL
50  Z   51  +   NULL
51  Y   107 /   NULL
52  B   107 /   NULL
53  B   108 +   NULL
```

I am looking to get the relation parent/child so I define the following class:

```
class Node { 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int? ParentId { get; set; } 
    public string Operator { get; set; } 
    public string Sign { get; set; } 
    public Node Parent { get; set; } 
    public IList Children { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " " + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => x.Id));
        return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " "
        + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => string.Format("({0}, {1})", x.Sign, x.Id)));
    }
}

public void GetChild(Node node, Dictionary<int, Node> map, Dictionary<int, Node> mapf)
{
    foreach (var child in node.Children)
    {
        foreach (var pairf in map)
        {
            if (child.Id == pairf.Value.ParentId)
            {
                child.Operator = pairf.Value.Operator;
                var parent = map[pairf.Value.ParentId.Value];


                child.Children.Add(pairf.Value);
                mapf[child.Id] = map[pairf.Value.Id];
                //rootNodes.Add(pairf.Value);
            }
        }
        GetChild(child,map,mapf);
    }
}
```

I have successfully got the rootnodes using this code

```
var map = new Dictionary(); var rootNodes = new List();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLId"]);
    int? parentId = null;
    if (!row.IsNull("PNLParentId"))
    {
        parentId = Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLParentId"]);
    }
    string op = Convert.ToString(row["Operator"]);
    string sign = Convert.ToString(row["Sign"]);
    map[id] = new Node
    {
        Id = id,
        ParentId = parentId,
        Operator = op,
        Sign = sign

    };
}

var mapf = new Dictionary<int, Node>();
 // get rootnods 
foreach (var pair in map)
{
    if (pair.Value.ParentId.Equals(null))
    {
        mapf[pair.Value.Id] = map[pair.Value.Id];
        rootNodes.Add(pair.Value);

    }
}
// get operator for rootnods 
foreach (var pair in mapf)
{
    foreach (var pairf in map)
    {
        if (pair.Value.Id == pairf.Value.ParentId)
        {
            pair.Value.Operator = pairf.Value.Operator; 
            var parent = map[pairf.Value.ParentId.Value];
            rootNodes.Add(pairf.Value);
            GetChild(rootNodes., map, mapf);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to build node tree first. Then start at the root nodes copying the operator from the children. Progress to the children and copy their children's operator.
For example

```
[92 Node: / 92 (, 36),(, 37)]
[93 Node: + 93 (, 38),(, 39),(, 40)]
[94 Node: / 94 (, 69),(, 70)]
[95 Node: + 95 (, 81),(, 82)]
[96 Node: + 96 (, 83),(, 84),(, 85),(, 86),(, 87),(, 88),(, 89)]
```

The code above doesn't return this result . How can I modify it ?

Comment: Did you delete and re-post this? Again: make sure you indent all lines of code by 4 spaces (and more spaces for further indenting). Do not use tabs.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: the code above doesn't work .

Comment: What does it do wrong?

Comment: I hope you didn't wrote this code by yourself

Comment: What is `GetChild` actually supposed to do?

Comment: Okay, from your edit: "start at the root nodes copying the operator from the children" what does that mean, precisely?

Comment: @user3548593 It's clearer but I still don't understand what "copying the operator from the children" means. If a node has operator "+", and its 4 children have operators "+", "-", "/" and "/", what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Posted some code. I'm still not 100% if I understand what you need. If it doesn't work, please post an exact input that it's wrong for, the output you get, and the output that you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from scratch:

```
public IEnumerable<Node> CreateTree(DataTable table)
{
    var nodes = GetNodes(table).ToList();
    var roots = new List<Node>();
    foreach(var node in nodes)
    {
        if(node.ParentId==null)
            roots.Add(node);
        else
        {
            var parent = nodes.Single(n => n.Id == node.ParentId);
            CreateRelationship(parent, node);
        }
    }

    foreach (var root in roots)
    {
        UpdateOperators(root);
    }

    return nodes;
}

private void CreateRelationship(Node parent, Node child)
{
    child.Parent = parent;
    parent.Children.Add(child);
}

private IEnumerable<Node> GetNodes(DataTable table)
{
    return from DataRow row in table.Rows select CreateNode(row);
}

private Node CreateNode(DataRow row)
{
    return new Node
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLId"]),
        ParentId = row.IsNull("PNLParentId") ? default(int?) : Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLParentId"]),
        Operator = Convert.ToString(row["Operator"]),
        Sign = Convert.ToString(row["Sign"])
    };
}

private void UpdateOperators(Node parent)
{
    if (!parent.Children.Any())
        return;
    parent.Operator = parent.Children.First().Operator;
    foreach (var child in parent.Children)
    {
        UpdateOperators(child);
    }
}
```

`Node` should keep everything from your code except the `GetChild` method. Also, `Children` should be declared as an `IList<Node>`, not an `IList`.

`CreateTree` is your point of entry- it returns an `IEnumerable` of all nodes, with all parent/child relationships throughout the tree correct.

Comment: How it will be the main program ?

Comment: @user3548593 You posted two snippets of code. Wherever you had the second snippet, instead now you need a call to `CreateTree`, with your `DataTable` (which you called `dt`) passed in as the parameter.

Comment: How can I write the result in a text file ?

Comment: You can do something like `var roots = CreateTree(dt); foreach(root in roots){ sw.WriteLine(root.ToString()); }`. There `sw` would be a `StreamWriter`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamwriter for an example of how to use that class.

Comment: when I execute   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Desktop\t.txt"))
                    {
                        foreach (var root in result.CreateTree(dt)) { sw.WriteLine(root.ToString()); } I got Node:  90 
Node:  91 
Node:  92 
Node:  93 
Node:  94 
Node:  95 
Node:  96 

                    } without operator children

Comment: @user3548593 Edit the full input table you're testing with into your question and I'll test it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52329/discussion-between-user3548593-and-ben-aaronson)